# Adding title for each of the two side by side plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two plots side by side. I'd like to be able to put a title on each graph but I can't figure out how to do this. Here is the snippet of my code I'm trying to add it to.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(15, 3))
axes[0].plot(X_TSNE, 'b*')
axes[1].plot(Z_TSNE, 'r*')
fig.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
axes[0].set_title('Title A')
axes[1].set_title('Title B')
```